# Displaying images in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Try with a specific folder to display an image, but does not work, tell me what I was doing wrong and where, what can it not enough? All images are in the folder `C:\dip\todo`. Use runserver.

#### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/dip/todo/' 
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin-media/'
```

#### admin.py

```
class StatAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ): 
  list_display = ( 'title', 'image')
```

#### models.py

```
class Stat( models.Model ): 
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 255,verbose_name = "Статистика" ) 
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')

  def __unicode__( self ): 
    return u"%s" % self.title

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Статистика' 
    verbose_name_plural = 'Диаграммы'
```

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns( '',
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

#### base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %} 
{% load i18n %} 
{% block title %}{{ title }} | Реестр инплантатов{% endblock %}
{% block branding %} 
<h1 id="site-name">Реестр инплантатов</h1> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: We'll need to see your view code and the template code which is showing the image to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your media url says:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

But in urls you have:

```
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Try changing `site_media` to `media` and it should work

Comment: No, it does not work, I'm not sure that everything correctly configured in the template 'base_site.html and madels.py

Comment: @user723603 - this answer fixes at least part of the problem, but we'll need more details to help you out.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
In this issue, and I do not quite understand what is required to describe in view.py and what exactly you want to add to the template base_site.html.?